# Chrome : pasting a url with a custom protocol does a search instead of opening the associate app

Tags: google-chrome

I'm running `Windows 10` and `Chrome`, and I have an app installed that is able to handle URLs with a certain custom protocol, say:

```
npp:blahblahblah
```

the problem is this: if I click on a link with that URL within a page the associate app gets launched correctly. However, if I paste the same URL in the address bar and press enter, it just searches the URL on google.

How do I force Chrome to open the link instead of searching?
NOTE: with Edge, it works correctly, only Chrome has this problem

Comment: **Register a** [Custom Protocol Handler](https://developers.google.com/s/results/?q=custom+protocol+handler&p=%2Fweb%2F). [More Jelp Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7087728/7975442).

Comment: @C0deDaedalus: the handler IS registeredi in the system (it's a native application, not a webapp). All browsers handle it correctly, including Chrome when you *click* on such a link... it only fails if you PASTE it in the address bar, because it automatically performs a google search instead of opening it as a link

Comment: Now that Edge is Chromium it has the same problem.